# What’s the best switch with bandwidth limiter for my Internet Cafe?

Tags: networking, latency

I'm looking for the best switch and router for my internet cafe, that have bandwith limiter and have low latency... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A switch won't be helpful. You need something like a captive portal.

It can be installed on a router or firewall.

pfsense (very easy, with web interface) has several captive portals installed. you should give a look at it.

Comment: Not that I think your portal recommendation is wrong, but why do you think the OP can't do bandwidth-limiting on a switch, or that this will be unhelpful?

Comment: Because switches also would limit cross traffic, like for local games. Also, switches are not handling TCP level but ethernet level - tp level is a router.

Comment: Oh, I dunno.. You could fork out for a Cisco L3 Switch.  Not a great use of money though.

Comment: Ok thanks for the reply I'll have a look about captive portal, never heards that word before...